# Windows 10 не видит вай фай сети

Tags: сеть, windows-10, драйвер

Возникла такая проблема. В один момент интернет после запуска пк стал отключаться и невозможно было подключиться к нему. После 3 перезапусков ноутбук вообще перестал видеть вай фай сети. Я вроде уже переустановил сетевой драйвер, но не помогает. Автоматическое исправление windows пишет, что сетевой кабель подключен неправильно или повреждён. Так вот у меня нет сетевого кабеля так как я хочу подключиться к беспроводному роутеру.